# How to unzip a .vw.gz file in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, unzip

How can I unzip a .vw.gz file in Linux? 
`tar -xvf filename` 
throws errors.

Comment: Given the .gz,  try 'gunzip'

Comment: Yeah. that helped. I don't know why the question is being downvoted. I searched for many queries related to decompressing .vw.gz file and apparently, there aren't any references available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.gz` is a gzipped file and is not related to `tar`. You do, more often then not, see a tarred and gzipped file that is first tarred, then gzipped (like `somfile.tar.gz`) but those are two seperate operations (that are supported by a single `tar` command.

To unzip a gzipped file you use the `gunzip` command.

```
gunzip filename.vw.gz
```

The confusion here is that many of us are used to `.zip` files. `zip` fulfills two needs.

1. The need to put multiple files into a single file (archive)
2. The need to compress the file/archive.

`tar` is an archiving program. If you check out it's manpage in Ubuntu `man tar` you'll see:

> tar — The GNU version of the tar archiving utility

`gzip` is a compression program. It's manpage `man gzip` reads:

> gzip, gunzip, zcat - compress or expand files

So in this case we have two programs to compress and archive.

The other confusing bit is that we almost always use the `tar` command to do both archiving and compressing, but you'll see in it's manpage that you can specify the compression program to use. For instance we can compress in `tar` using the bzip compression algorithm:

```
tar -jcvf archive_name.tar.bz2 /path/to/some/dir
```

Comment: This. Also, `gzip` and `gunzip` will remove original file when the compression/decompression operation is complete - you'll only have either the compressed version, or the uncompressed version.  `bzip2` operates the same way.

Comment: Yes thanks for the answer. Any idea why gzip doesn't have a flag which enables you to also keep the original compressed file?

Comment: It does. You can learn a ton by hitting the manpage `man gzip`. You'll see `-k --keep
              Keep (don't delete) input files during compression or decompression.` as an option.

Comment: @JNevill actually I did that and `gzip 1.5` doesn't seem to be having these flags...